# Check if a function has fired in Jest

Tags: jestjs

I have a class which starts and fires off a setup function in the constructor like so:

```
import { myFunction } from './util';

export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    myFuction()
  }
}
```

And then inside that function I have this:

```
export function myFunction() {
  window.fruit = 'apple';
}
```

I want to test in Jest that the `myFunction()` function gets fired, and that `window.fruit` has the property of Apple.

```
import MyClass from '../index';
import { myFunction } from '../util';

describe('myclass', () => {
  const mocks = {
    myFunction: jest.fn()
  }

  const meinclass = new MyClass();

  describe('#constructor', () => {
    it('should initialize the class', () => {
      expect(meinclass).not.toBeUndefined()
    })

    it('should call myfunction', () => {
      const init = jest.spyOn(myFunction);
      const fruit = window.fruit

      expect(init).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(fruit).toBe('apple')
    })
  })

})
```

I am unsure of the correct way of testing this? I've tried using the `.mock` method of Jest also but I seem to be struggling to get it to work. Whenever I even log `window` I don't see the property `fruit` on it. I feel like there's a larger part of this puzzle I'm missing. Apologies for the simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it make sense to test both, that the function was called and that `window.fruit` was set correctly. So instead of using `window` use `global`. Doing it this way you don't need to mock anything.

```
it('should call myfunction', () => {
  const fruit = global.fruit
  expect(fruit).toBe('apple')
})
```

The other way would be only to test that the function was called:

```
import MyClass from '../index';
import { myFunction } from '../util';

jest.mock('../util', ()=>({myFunction: jest.fn()}))

it('should call myfunction', () => {
  expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```